# How to debug a program that runs but doesn't stop?

Tags: java

I have written a program to sort numbers in both Ascending and Descending order. Here is the output:

> "Enter numbers to sort" input numbers {4 3 2 6}
>
> "Type 'A' for Ascending order 'B' for descending order" input A
> output: 2 3 4 6

This program runs giving the correct output except that it doesn't exit automatically in command prompt. When I press ctrl-c I get a message "exception in thread "main"".

I am trying to find where I went wrong for a while now but with no success.

Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter numbers to sort");
        String str = in.nextLine();
        String[] splitted = str.trim().split("\\s+");
        int len = splitted.length;
        int a[] = new int[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitted[i]);
        }
        boolean TryAgain = true;
        System.out.println("How to sort: Type 'A' for Ascending and 'B' for Descending order");

        while (TryAgain=true) {

            char SortType = in.next().charAt(0);

            if (SortType == 'A' || SortType == 'a' || SortType == 'B' || SortType == 'b') {// first if

                if (SortType == 'A' || SortType == 'a') {// second if loop
                    // code for sorting in Ascending order
                    for (int j = 0; j < len - 1; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < len - j - 1; k++) {
                            if (a[k] > a[k + 1]) {
                                int n = a[k];
                                a[k] = a[k + 1];
                                a[k + 1] = n;
                            } // for
                        } // for
                    } // if
                    System.out.println("Numbers sorted in Ascending order:");
                    for (int m = 0; m < len; m++) {
                        System.out.print(a[m] + " ");
                    } // for
                    TryAgain = false;
                } // second if loop


                else {// second else
                        // code for sorting in Dscending order
                    for (int j = 0; j < len - 1; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < len - j - 1; k++) {
                            if (a[k] < a[k + 1]) {
                                int n = a[k];
                                a[k] = a[k + 1];
                                a[k + 1] = n;
                            } // for
                        } // for
                    } // if
                    System.out.println("Numbers sorted in Dscending order:");
                    for (int m = 0; m < len; m++) {
                        System.out.print(a[m] + " ");
                    } // for
                    TryAgain = false;
                } // second else loop
            } // first if loop

            else {// first else
                TryAgain = true;
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                System.out.println("Type 'A' for Ascending and 'B' for Descending order:");
            } // first else loop

        } // while loop


    }// main
}// class
```

Comment: Try changing `while(TryAgain=true)` to `while(TryAgain)` and stopping harmful assignment.

Comment: Please format your code. No wonder you can't find your mistakes ;)

Comment: Indenting is widely used way for making correspondence of blaces clear instead of adding comments.

Comment: You're pasting the same code in different questions. And whoch IDE are you using? All Java IDEs that I know, support **Ctrl + Shift + F** to autoformat your code.

Answer (score 3):

Change `while(TryAgain=true)` to `while(TryAgain)` so that `true` won't be assigned to `TryAgain` there and have the `while` statement see the value of `TryAgain`.

Answer (score 1):

When you type

```
   while(tryAgain=true)
```

It assigns true to tryAgain irrespective of what was assigned previously. This means that the loop will remain true no matter what. In your code we see that you have already initialized the boolean variable tryAgain to true. So, there is no need to do so again. This is the mistake you are making in the while loop thereby keeping I continuously active. Further in your code when you make the value of tryAgain false, it reinitialises itself in the while loop and keeps the loop going on. Instead when you write

```
    while(tryAgain)
```

It gives you the flexibility to change the value of tryAgain. So when you change its value to false, it remains false. Also if you are if you want, you could change your code to

```
    while(tryAgain==true)
```

Just to save the trouble of deleting ;). The above snippet will work in the same way. It will compare if the value of tryAgain is true or false and if it is true, it will execute the while loop else come out of it

Answer (score 0):

if you do this.

```
while(TryAgain=true){
```

then your `while` loop is running for ever...

modify it

Answer (score 0):

Closing parentheses are missing for most IF statements. Indent your code properly to find missing parentheses.